# How to add a scroll bar at the move list view? And user can only scroll specific area vertically

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi

I am using MVC for my project. And I have few views in View. However, I want to know how to add a scrollbar to one view and only make that part can be scrolled vertically.

I have tried using `CreateWindowW()` for adding `WM_VSCROLL` parameter, but it does not work.

This is a TUI application, so I think the professor try to make us using a cell as bar, so you can scroll the cell up and down

Comment: `CreateWindow` expects `WS_VSCROLL` style not `WM_VSCROLL` message.

Answer (score 0):

In `PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)`, set `cs.style |= WS_VSCROLL;`.

You may have to respond to WM_VSCROLL to process scroll messages.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusing. I am resisted to use TUI only. And I misunderstood what the professor needed. So he wanted us to move a color cell so you can scroll up and down for checking player's moves. I am making a Gomoku Game by using C++. So I figure it out, right now my move list view can move up and down for viewing full moves. Thanks for all the answers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBWYk.png)